# my_text_ + Var_with_number (dynamique var)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this (in Javascript):

```
function Ajout(Nom)
{
    Nombre_ligne = Nombre_ligne + 1 ;
    Produit_X = [Nom,6] ;
}
```

I want to replace the "X" in the var "Produit_X" with the value of the var "Nombre_ligne".

I search since 3 hours, i have try with "Window" and "eval" but no result (i think cause its not adapt).

Comment: If you want to set a global variable you should be able to use `window['Produit_' + Nombre_ligne] = [Nom, 6]`. There is no way to access locally-scoped variables using strings without eval (which is a no-no). You could always go the OOP route and use new `Ajout();` and set `this['Produit_' + Nombre_ligne] = [Nom, 6]`;

Comment: I'm assuming you already used the declaration of `var` to `Nombre_ligne` and `Produit_X`?